# Pydev keeps forgetting interpreter settings, "unknown encoding: idna" keeps showing up in logs

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Every time I restart Eclipse, none of my python3 files open because eclipse says they use the wrong interpreter settings. When I go resolve the interpreter settings I see that none of the configuration I made is there, and I have to set a new interpreter. Every time.

I've checked and as far as I can tell Eclipse has write access to all the locations where it writes configuration to in my Windows system. I checked the logs, and see the same error repeated over and over:

```
 - Err output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.3.202301231743\pysrc\pycompletionserver.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants import IS_JYTHON
  File "C:\Users\me\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.3.202301231743\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 32, in <module>
    _codecs.lookup(_codec)
LookupError: unknown encoding: idna

!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating python process - exited before creating sockets - exitValue = (1).
ProcessInfo:

 - Executed: C:\Windows\py.exe -u C:\Users\me\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_10.1.3.202301231743\pysrc\pycompletionserver.py 58747
```

I also see the following stack trace sometimes when the error appears:

```
    at org.python.pydev.core.log.Log.log(Log.java:33)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.startIt(AbstractShell.java:287)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:240)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.shell.ShellsContainer.getServerShell(ShellsContainer.java:168)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.shell.AbstractShell.getServerShell(AbstractShell.java:219)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.createTokensFromServer(CompiledModule.java:377)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.modules.CompiledModule.<init>(CompiledModule.java:180)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.modules.AbstractModule.createModule(AbstractModule.java:293)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.ModulesManager.getModule(ModulesManager.java:1038)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.ModulesManager.getModule(ModulesManager.java:869)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.SystemModulesManager.getModule(SystemModulesManager.java:400)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AbstractAdditionalDependencyInfo.updateKeysIfNeededAndSave(AbstractAdditionalDependencyInfo.java:259)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.system_info_builder.InterpreterInfoBuilder.syncInfoToPythonPath(InterpreterInfoBuilder.java:171)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.system_info_builder.InterpreterInfoBuilder.syncInfoToPythonPath(InterpreterInfoBuilder.java:97)
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.system_info_builder.InterpreterInfoBuilder.syncInfoToPythonPath(InterpreterInfoBuilder.java:83)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.SyncSystemModulesManager.synchronizeManagerToNameToInfoPythonpath(SyncSystemModulesManager.java:392)
    at org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.revisited.SyncSystemModulesManagerScheduler$SynchJob.run(SyncSystemModulesManagerScheduler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: That's the [PyDev plugin](https://www.pydev.org), not Eclipse itself. Please make sure your issue has been reported with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to PyDev, best with a patch. Please be aware that Stack Overflow is to ask questions, not to report bugs.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line it says that you've configured `C:\Windows\py.exe` an the python interpreter, which is definitely wrong.

So, if you configure the interpreter it should fix the `idna` issue. Now as to why it's not persisting the information, as far as I remember the only case where I've seen this was when a user was using `Oomph` to save workspace settings and then replicate those settings but then wrongly saved PyDev interpreter settings to nothing in `Oomph`. Can you check if this is your case?